# How to go on websites that block or flag Tor IP addresses

Tags: privacy, tor

I've noticed of late a good number of websites block Tor using either Google ReCaptcha or its other popular compatriot.  Has anyone figured out how to go around this while still using Tor?  With the latter, you click a few images of buses, traffic signs, or roads and you are in but Google is brutal and won't allow you in.

Is Tor making any progress to rectify this e.g. adding any IP addresses on a minute by minute basis?

Comment: PrivacyPass may help with some of your issues: https://privacypass.github.io/

Comment: Shouldn't be this migrated to: https://tor.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The only solution would be to use a proxy after Tor. Unfortunately this has the tendency to reduce your anonymity when done too often as you no longer have a rotating exit point. One solution would be to use any number of popular CGI web proxies, or to switch to a service which doesn't block Tor.

It is not possible for Tor to avoid this by adding new exit nodes frequently as the list is necessarily public. IP blacklist services that block Tor merely use this list. Furthermore, exit nodes are run by and paid for by the community. Tor Project cannot just snap their fingers and add fresh exits.